# Laravel no trabaja con la database especificada

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, connection

Quiero que laravel utilice la base de datos que tengo en local, para ello modifique mi archivo .env de esta forma:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=accounting_system
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Y mi archivo de database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'accounting_system'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

Sin embargo, laravel sigue trabajando con una database de un hosting gratuito con la que trabaje anteriormente.
Gracias de antemano. Diego

Comment: Haz intentado de limpiar las caches? ej. `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Lo intentaré, xq no conozco los comandos para "refrescar" los combios q haga, yo había probado con composer dumpautoload

Comment: Muchas gracias funcionó. perdon por la ignorancia, hace unas semanas empece con laravel